# Javascript - Return modified object passed by reference

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

I know that Javascript's objects are passed by a copy of a reference to a function.

In that sense, if I have a function that modifies the object, should I return the object and overwrite the original or not?

I.e, this

```
function inc(obj)
{
    obj.count++;
}

obj = {count : 0, topic : 'Something'};
inc(obj);
```

vs this:

```
function inc(obj)
{
    obj.count++;
    return obj;
}

obj = {count : 0, topic : 'Something'};
obj = inc(obj);
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: If you already know that JS copies a reference so that your function is operating on the original object, why would you think it would make a difference? Your question seems arbitrary. It's like saying *"I know `1 + 2` will yield the same result as `2 + 1`, so which order should I use?"*

Comment: "Better"? By what criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the function returns the value passed in, then there's really no point - the value of the external variable "obj" cannot be changed by the function in any case.

It's not exactly correct to say that anything in JavaScript is "passed by reference". Object "values" are *always* references, and parameter passing is no exception. JavaScript is a strictly pass-by-value language; it's just that values that happen to be references to objects are, well, references to objects. So what you say in the opening of your question is correct: a copy of the reference to the object is passed into the function. The topic of parameter passing is one that's simple but complicated, and complicated not the least by the fact that the word "reference" appears in the technical "language theory" term "pass-by-reference".

Now, in a situation where your function might, for some reason, decide that it needs to create a *new* object, then returning an object might make sense.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake with the second case. I meant to increment the count, and then return the entire object. See above please.

Comment: Okay thanks, this makes more sense. I'll vote this whenever the timer runs out.

Comment: Your middle paragraph is really not very clear.  I understand what's happening in JS (as do you), but if I didn't, that middle paragraph wouldn't help me to understand it and telling a newbie that everything is pass by value rarely sends their thinking in the right direction.  I prefer to explain to people that when you pass an object in JS, what gets passed to the function is a reference to the object itself (not a reference to the containing variable).  When you pass a primitive, it is passed purely by value.  This tends to send their thinking in the right direction.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it's a complicated thing to explain especially to those for whom it most needs explaining. In this case I should probably just get rid of it entirely :)

Comment: @jfriend00: It's not that "when you pass an object", somehow they use a reference just for passing. "An object" is simply not a value in JS. When you create an object, you get a reference back; the operators that allow you to access a field take a reference as the left operand; when you assign, it assigns one reference to another. Basically, *everywhere*, you only ever deal with references. You never have a value that "is an object". There is nothing special about passing -- it's the same with all other operations.